# NuGet package linking issues with Visual Studio cross-platform projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, cross-platform

When using the "OpenGLES 2 Application (Android, iOS, Windows Universal)" template in Visual Studio 2015, NuGet packages I add to the solution aren’t linking in the Android native projects.  Installed NuGet packages build and run fine in the Windows Universal projects.  (I'm not concerned with iOS projects.)  As I understand it, Clang on Windows will link Windows-OS library target files.

None of the SO questions I could find dealt with NuGet specifically in relation to cross-platform projects.

(The packages I’ve mainly been trying to work with are libpng and zlib, but I tried a couple of random other ones and got the same results, so I don’t believe this is package-specific.)

The program compiles, so clearly it sees the headers.  But the linker can’t find the library dependencies, and gives me `error : undefined reference to '(some function)'` messages for anything referenced in - and only in - NuGet packages.

Here’s what I’ve tried.  To the serious detriment of my sanity, all of the below had no apparent affect, nor changed the error messages from the linker:

- Performed a Visual Studio repair.
- Reinstalled the NuGet Package Manager.
- Manually added the libraries’ paths to the linker options.  I even tried `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` via the `-fms-compatibility` flag.
- Manually inspected the paths in the packages.config files for each project (and any other file with any sort of path in it I could find in the project files).
- Created a new solution.

Does NuGet not work with Visual Studio Android projects, or am I missing something?  Should I just forget about NuGet in cross-platform projects and build everything myself?

I appreciate any suggestions whatsoever.  Thank you.

Comment: The libpng supported platform is Unix, DOS, Windows, and so on, which is not list Android. Please refer to: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html  And I find most of the Native packages in NuGet Package Manager list are not support Android. Please tell us other packages that you have tried, I will check them in my side to check whether the packages also doesn't support Android. If possible, please share a sample project about how do you use these packages in Android project, it is benefit to help us reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Wendy libpng is definitely usable on Android platforms. I was only hoping NuGet might make things a little easier in that specific Visual Studio environment.